# MVC3 Dropdown list and Bootstrap Modal does select the server value of the list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3

Well, im using .Net MVC3 with razor and the modals from bootstrap to make a web page.

This is my view:

```
Clientes: @Html.DropDownList("Clientes", new SelectList(Datamodel.GestorDatos.ConjuntoClientes.ListarClientesStatic(), "Codigo", "Empresa", 24), new {@class = "form-control chosen", id = "Clientes" })
```

I'm sending from the server two objects one with the primary key 23 and another with the primary key 24 those two objects are in a "IEnumerable" object.
I don't know why with the modal always choose me the 23 value as default.

Comment: Because either the value of property `Clientes` is `23`, or its value does not match one of the options and the option with `23` is the first one in the collection. When you bind to a property, its the value of the property that determines which option is selected. Your use of the parameter you have set to `24` is ignored (you can remove it)

Comment: Short story probably is because by default the first option in select is selected. beyond that the server rendering of a select should have nothing to do with the modal window, it would do the same if it wasn't in a modal

Answer (score 0):

By default the top most value will be selected and it seems this default behavior is kicking in for some reason. But I tried out your code it works as expected for me. My guess is your returned collection did not have matching value element. You can see your example running here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yPwHDB